# Meaning of "but beg security will bolt the door"

Tags: meaning, lord-byron, don-juan

From *[Don Juan](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)/Canto_the_First)* by Byron:

> LXXXVIII
>   "Oh Love! in such a wilderness as this,
>        Where transport and security entwine,
>   Here is the empire of thy perfect bliss,
>        And here thou art a god indeed divine."
>   The bard I quote from does not sing amiss,
>        With the exception of the second line,
>   For that same twining "transport and security"
>   Are twisted to a phrase of some obscurity.
>
> LXXXIX
>   The poet meant, no doubt, and thus appeals
>        To the good sense and senses of mankind,
>   The very thing which every body feels,
>        As all have found on trial, or may find,
>   That no one likes to be disturb'd at meals
>        Or love.—I won't say more about "entwined"
>   Or "transport," as we knew all that before,
>   **But beg 'security' will bolt the door**.

What is the meaning of this line?

It's a bit cryptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The verb "beg" goes with "I", and "security" is personified.**

Byron first quotes Campbell's poem ["Gertrude of Wyoming"](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gertrude_of_Wyoming), and then comments on the phrase "transport and security" from it. The words "entwined" and "transport" are both interpreted sexually - the poem suggests the idea of lovers, their bodies *entwined*, being *transported* by their uncontrollable urges. He coyly doesn't go into the details explicitly, because "we knew all that before"; instead, he focuses on "security", unsubtly foreshadowing the lack of security in Juan and Julia's affair which ultimately led to their discovery:

> I won't say more about "entwined"
>   Or "transport," as we knew all that before,
>   But [I] beg [that] "security" will bolt the door.

Rephrased: *the personified "security" should bolt the door on the lovers, so that they can enjoy their "transport" and being "entwined" without fear of being disturbed.*